# AnnotationView overlapping on calloutVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm using MapKit for displaying data on a map. For that, I'm using Custom AnnotationView and Custom CalloutView. But problem is that when I have AnnotationView to close each other at that time AnnotationView is overlapping on CalloutView. Here is a screenshot of the problem.
[image: overlapping annotationView]

There is also a problem with buttons, button's click event is not getting called. The 4 buttons on the downside of calloutView are not getting called on tap. But the button on the top right which is representing edit event is getting fired on tapping.

Here is my code for CalloutView.

```
@implementation CustomCalloutView

- (id)init {

        return self;
}
- (IBAction)btnEditAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.delegate btnEditClicked];
}

- (IBAction)btnMailAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.delegate btnMailClicked];
}

- (IBAction)btnMessageAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.delegate btnMessageClicked];
}

- (IBAction)btnCallAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.delegate btnCallClicked];

}

- (IBAction)btnStreetAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.delegate btnStreetClicked];
}
- (IBAction)CalloutTapGestureClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    [self.delegate CalloutTApGesture:sender];
}
@end
```

Please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Do this to prevent overlap ( Insert callOut view at top )

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
 {

   print("clickedddddddd")

    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        return
    }

        let customView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customSou", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! customSouOut;

        var calloutViewFrame = customView.frame;
        calloutViewFrame.origin = CGPoint(x:-calloutViewFrame.size.width/2 + 15,y: -calloutViewFrame.size.height);
        customView.frame = calloutViewFrame;


        view.addSubview(customView)


         // here you can fill any label or button with data according to it's pin 

         //

        for v in view.subviews
        {
            if v is customSouOut
            {
                continue
            }
            else
            {
                view.insertSubview(customView, aboveSubview: v)
            }
        }

    }

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView)
{
     print("oppspspspsps")

    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        return
    }

     for v in view.subviews
    {
        if v is customSouOut 
        {
            v.removeFromSuperview()

            break
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: what is customSouOut?

Comment: It's custom view you want as the callout view , in your example the view that contains the buttons that can't work